# Azure VM automated deploy

Tags: deployment, azure, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a VM running in Azure and I have a Console Application that run in that VM.

In parallel on that, I have Team Foundation Service with my source code and a CI running. I want the Build Server deploy that Console Application every time a build is succeded.

It's possible using a VM and a Console Application ?

Comment: Is your VM running a Cloud Service (PaaS) or Virtual Machine (IaaS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thinking Out Loud]
One possibility would be to set up a FTP Server on your VM and then once the build is successful, you could possibly push the console application binaries to your VM using FTP. I'm not sure how this would work if your console application is already running in your VM or if you would need to launch the application once it is copied over successfully to your VM. But I'm sure you could come up with a small application/service running in the VM which can manage that.

Answer (score 0):

This link is for TeamCity (which is also CI server) but you could get the powershell script and apply it on a build step.

https://gist.github.com/srkirkland/3694398

You should have a build step which actually is used to deploy to Azure on your configuration.